# FB.login not authtorized

Tags: facebook, canvas

I am designing a Facebook app on canvas page. And I called the Facebook_login function when clicking on a button. Wnen I visit the app and click on the button, it always works and shows "connected". But when using the tester facebook account the response.status is always "not_authorized", whatever the tester authorized the app or not. I am really confused about this. Could anybody figure it out for me? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

function Facebook_login() {

```
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

    if (response.status == 'connected') {
      alert(response.status);
     var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
     var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
     var signed_request = response.authResponse.signedRequest;
    } else if (response.status == 'not_authorized') {
      alert(response.status);
      login();
    } else {
     //cancelled
    }
```

}, true);
}

function login() {
     FB.login(function(response) {

```
    if (response.authResponse) {
      var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
       console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/'+uid, function(response) {
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        });
    } else {
        // cancelled    
    }
 },{scope:'email,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream'});
```

}

Comment: Ever get a solution to this?  I'm having the same problem